# Aligning two different tabularray environments with 2 and 3 columns

Tags: tables, minipage, tabularray

I have defined two environments using `tabularray` and would like to have the vertical line aligned. The problem is that it needs to be aligned for different widths (with or without a minipage environment around it). **Note**: I am quite happy about the `CV_table` environment and would like to change it as little as possible. If possible, only change the `CV_text` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=23mm,right=23mm, bindingoffset=0mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{CVbody}{%
        \hspace{-0.5cm}\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}\raggedright
    }{%
        \end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}
    }%

% The tabularray environments:

\newenvironment{CV_table}{%
    \par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent
    \begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={@{} X[l,2] | X[l,3.8] X[l,3.5] @{}},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    width=1.1\textwidth,
    colsep = 15pt,
    rowsep=0.5\baselineskip}%
    }%
    { \end{tblr} \par\addvspace{\topsep} }

\newenvironment{CV_text}{%
    \par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent
    \begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={@{} X[l,1.7] | X[l,7.3] @{}},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    width=1.1\textwidth,
    colsep = 15pt,
    rowsep=0.5\baselineskip}%
    }%
    { \end{tblr} \par\addvspace{\topsep} }
    

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{CVbody}

\begin{CV_table}
 {First column} & {second column} & {some text here}
\end{CV_table}

\begin{CV_text}
 {First column} & { text goes here }
\end{CV_text}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{CVbody}


\end{document}
```

Output using `CVbody` environment (a minipage):

[image]

Output without using `CVbody` environment:

[image]

Comment: In fact with the `CVbody` the vertical lines aren't aligned either. But because the tables are narrower than without the `CVbody`, the difference is much smaller, so much that you can only notice it if you zoom in. I think the only ways to get them aligned are (1) make the width of the first column explicitly the same in both tables, or (2) put them in one table and use SetCell to make the righthand column in the lower part span the two columns.

Comment: I can not use option 2, as the tables will be seperated by headings and text. How do I go about stating the width of the first column explicit?

Comment: You use something like `p{3cm}`.

Comment: ``p{3}`` does not work in the ``tabularray`` environment.

Comment: In `tabularray` you would use `t{3cm}`, `m{3cm}` or `b{3cm}` depending on the desired vertical alignment. In your case I think `t` is best.